# Reason for overflow or underflow statement in solidity 0.8.16

Tags: solidity, error, hardhat-deploy

```
   //------------------------
   // EXECUTING ORDERS
   //------------------------

   function fillOrder(uint256 _id) public {
    // 1. Must be valid orderID
    require(_id > 0 && _id <= orderCount , 'order does not exist');
    // 2. Order can't be filled
    require(!orderFilled[_id]); 
    // 3. Order can't be cancelled
    require(!orderCancelled[_id]); 



    // Fetch Order
    _Order storage _order = orders[_id] ;

   // Executing Tokens

   _trade(
    _order.id,
    _order.user,
    _order.tokenGet,
    _order.amountGet,
    _order.tokenGive,
    _order.amountGive
   );

   // mark order as filled
   orderFilled[_order.id] = true ;
   

   }

   function _trade(
    uint256 _orderId,
    address _user,
    address _tokenGet,
    uint256 _amountGet,
    address _tokenGive,
    uint256 _amountGive
   ) internal {

    // Fee is paid by the user who filled the order(msg.sender)
    // Fee is deducted from _amountGet
    uint256 _feeAmount = (_amountGet * feePercent) / 100 ;
   // uint256 _feeAmount = 1 ;

    // Do The Trade Here ....

    // Execute the trade
    // Here The guy who is fulfilling the order is msg.sender and whom from he receives is the _user

    tokens[_tokenGet][msg.sender] = tokens[_tokenGet][msg.sender] - (_amountGet + _feeAmount);
    tokens[_tokenGet][_user] = tokens[_tokenGet][_user] + _amountGet ;

    // Charge Fees
    tokens[_tokenGet][feeAccount] = tokens[_tokenGet][feeAccount] + _feeAmount ;


    // vice-versa

    tokens[_tokenGive][_user] = tokens[_tokenGive][_user] - _amountGive ;
    tokens[_tokenGive][msg.sender] = tokens [_tokenGive][msg.sender] + _amountGive ;

    // Emit Event
    emit Trade (
     _orderId,
     msg.sender,
     _tokenGet,
     _amountGet,
     _tokenGive,
     _amountGive,
     _user,
     block.timestamp
    );


   }
```

}

// And this is my seed exchange script

```
 //---------------------------------------------------------------
 // Seed Fill Orders
 //---------------------------------------------------------------

 // User1 makes order

 transaction = await exchange.connect(user1).makeOrder(mETH.address,tokens(100),DApp.address,tokens(10))
 result = await transaction.wait()
 console.log(`Made order from ${user1.address}`)

 // User2 fills order

 orderId = result.events[0].args.id
```

//  console.log(orderId)

```
  transaction = await exchange.connect(user2).fillOrder(orderId)
  result = await transaction.wait()
 console.log(`Order filled by ${user2.address}`)

  // Wait 1 second
  await wait(1)
```

please help and tell me where i am doing wrong with my code[image: This the error message]

[image: and this one]

Comment: Sorry but there is way too much code. Please try to reduce the code to minimum to pinpoint the problematic point.

Comment: done i changed it

Comment: Is there a part of the code where you have unchecked{} brackets set?

Comment: i tried but that did'nt work. so i removed